# Cypher: Adding properties to relationship as distinct values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I'm trying to do is to write a query - I already made it a webservice(working on local machine, so I get the name and people as parameters) - which connects people who share the same hobbies and set the hobbies as the relationship property as an array.
My first attempt was;

```
MERGE (aa:Person{name:$name})
WITH aa, $people as people
FOREACH (person IN people |
MERGE (bb:Person{name:person.name})
MERGE (bb)-[r:SHARESSAMEHOBBY]->(aa)
ON MATCH SET r.hobbies = r.hobbies + person.hobby
ON CREATE SET r.hobbies = [person.hobby])
```

However this caused duplicated property elements like ["swimming","swimming"]

I'm trying to set only unique properties. Then I tried the following query;

```
MERGE (aa:Person{name:$name})
WITH aa, $people as people FOREACH (person IN people | MERGE (bb:Person{name:person.name}) MERGE (bb)-[r:SHARESSAMEHOBBY]->(aa)
WITH r, COALESCE(r.hobbies, []) + person.hobby AS hobbies
UNWIND hobbies as unwindedHobbies
WITH r, collect(distinct, unwindedHobbies) AS unique
set r.as = unique)
```

However now it gives me syntax error;

```
 errorMessage = "[Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError] Invalid use of WITH inside FOREACH
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MERGE (aa:Person {name: $name})
WITH aa
UNWIND $people AS person
MERGE (bb:Person {name: person.name})
MERGE (bb)-[r:SHARESSAMEHOBBY]-(aa)
WITH r, person, CASE
  WHEN NOT EXISTS(r.hobbies) THEN {new: true}
  WHEN NOT (person.hobby IN r.hobbies) THEN {add: true}
  END AS todo
FOREACH(ignored IN todo.new | SET r.hobbies = [person.hobby])
FOREACH(ignored IN todo.add | SET r.hobbies = r.hobbies + person.hobby);
```

You actually had 2 issues, and the above query addresses both:

1. If a `SHARESSAMEHOBBY` relationship already existed in the opposite direction (from `aa` to `bb`), the following `MERGE` clause would have caused the unnecessary creation of a second `SHARESSAMEHOBBY` relationship (from `bb` to `aa`):

   MERGE (bb)-[r:SHARESSAMEHOBBY]->(aa)

   To avoid this, you should have used a non-directional relationship pattern (which is is permitted by `MERGE`, but not `CREATE`) to match a relationship in either direction, like this:

   MERGE (bb)-[r:SHARESSAMEHOBBY]-(aa)
2. You needed to determine whether it is necessary to initialize a new `hobbies` list or to add the `person.hobby` value to an existing `r.hobbies` list that did not already have that value. The above query uses a `CASE` clause to assign to `todo` either `NULL`, or a map with a key indicating what additional work to do. It then uses a `FOREACH` clause to execute each thing to do, as appropriate.

Comment: When I try it, it says [Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError] Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' , any thoughts?

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when testing my answer. You apparently have a typo or some other syntax error (e.g., did you use `WITH` in the right places?). Where in the Cypher query was the error was found?

Comment: I found out the problem; I missed a ","

Thank you very much it worked like a charm!